Alice, Bob and Charlie - Who is lying?
We were given this exercise in logic class:
Three friends, Alice, Bob and Charlie, are talking to each other. They make three statements:

Alice says: ‘If Bob is telling the truth, then Charlie is lying.’
Bob says: ‘Alice is telling the truth.’
Charlie says: ‘Bob is lying.
The question: Who is telling the truth and who is lying?


Use logical consequence to analyze the statements and determine whether or not they are
are compatible with each other.
Try to construct a solution where the statements check their own consistency.
In this case, who is telling the truth and who is lying?

I understand that we should start this with:
$ A → (B → ¬C)$
$B  → A $
$C →  ¬ B$
but after that I'm kind of lost on what exactly I should do to find who lies and who tells the truth in proper formalism. How can I proceed with this exercise?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table

Each individual statement is an equivalence, not an implication (as lying or telling the truth refers only to this particular statement).
Thus, the second statement is A <-> B, ie we can replace B by A in the other two statements. The third statement becomes C <-> not B, so we can substitute (not C) by A in the first statement and get: A <-> (A -> A). Since A -> A is a tautology, we conclude that Alice and Bob are telling the truth and Charlie lies.

It's worth to note that the tautology A -> A trick here helping to determine the liar in classic logic depends on LEM. But in real world for such matters we may demand more strict constructive logic which doesn't accept LEM. So if A is lying (false), we cannot find a constructive proof (witness) for A even from itself since it's false without any witness. Intuitively this is very likely since A and B here apparently may form a false consensus simply by leveraging classic logic's tautological trick of non-constructive LEM while C is an honest yet strict intuitionist...

@DoubleKnot Not really. If I had worked constructively, I would have arrived at A -> not not A instead, which still a tautology.

You're right under a single naive view. What I meant is a likely real world possible collusion scenario where the honest constructivist C knows A and B are applying the common non-relevant non-constructive (sophist-like) classic logic to try to accuse C non-constructively like an assertive collusion. Then C cannot be rightfully counted as lying in such case, because C knows A is using LEM/DE so A's semantic and logic equivalent proposition won't be your constructive 'A -> not not A' at all, but simply 'A -> A'! This can be an interesting multi-agent epistemic logic exercise to see deeper...
